# How to have script ask for variable input and append input to text file

Tags: input, batch-file

So I have a script that works, but at the end of the script I would like to record the date, time, %username%, and ask for a name (that will be typed by the user)

This would all go into a "log" file.

What I have is:

```
echo Data Secured by %username% On %date% At %time% >> testfile.txt
```

This works fine.  But this is not asking for user input such as a name. I would like it to go like this:

-script will ask for "helper name?:"   and will allow ANY THING to be typed here.
It will then be inserted with the echo above to read:

```
 echo Data Secured by %username% & %helpername% On %date% At %time% >> testfile.txt
```

The result in the "log" file would be like this:

```
Data Secured by John & Jason on Fri 03/08/2013 At 15:29:27.19
```

The helper name can be anything.

I thought I would use something like

```
set /p helpername=" ? "
```

But this seems to be for YES NO answers or answers you can list, a persons name will change.

I hope this all makes sense....can someone please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the helper's name:

```
SET /P HelperName=Enter Helper Name:
```

And then this to save the data to the file:

```
ECHO Data Secured by %username% ^& %helpername% On %date% At %time%>>testfile.txt
```

Comment: With just those two lines in the script The result is:L:\>SET /P HelperName=Enter Helper Name:
Enter Helper Name:jason

L:\>ECHO Data Secured by Owner   & jason On Fri 03/08/2013 At 16:23:12.28 1>>tes
tfile.txt
Data Secured by Owner
'jason' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

L:\>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Actually, I made one small edit. I just realized you used an `&`. It will need to be escaped with a `^`.

Comment: What that is why it did not work for me? this whole time?? Jeez I could have made it say AND instead...arrg   THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: I am new to this site, is there a thank you for you on this site? I tried to upvote but I can not until I have 15 of something.

Comment: Note there are many hidden bugs and limitations (such as if a user inputs special characters as their name), but in all it's right.